# Constant Acceleration Question

Tags: acceleration

A Cessna 150 aircraft has a lift-off speed of approximately 125 $kmh^{-1}$.
What minimum constant acceleration does this require if the aircraft is to be airborne after a take-off run of 129 m?

So I wanted to use the formula that $x=\cfrac{(v_{final}^2 - v_{initial}^2)}{2a}$

To solve for the constant acceleration but I don't have a final velocity from this problem? My initial velocity is 125 $kmh^{-1}$ and my $x$ (displacement) would be 129 meters but how do I find the constant acceleration?

Comment: Can you not just assume your final velocity to be 125 $kmh^{-1}$ as that is the final velocity at take off in this situation? And surely initial velocity is 0 $kmh^{-1}$ as an aircraft starts from rest at the end of the runway?

Answer (score 3):

Let $V_{final}=34.72 ms^{-1}$ and $V_{initial}=0 ms^{-1}$ if $x=129m$:

Rearrange for a:

$\cfrac{V_{final}^2 - V_{initial}^2}{2x} = a$

$a=\frac{34.72^2-0}{2 \times 129}=4.67 ms^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Visualize the problem. The question is about a plane taking off. We are told that the lift-off speed is 125 km/h . Thus, just as Weasel said, this should be the speed at the *end* of the runway, just as the plane *lifts off* the ground. It seems reasonable to assume that the plane started its takeoff at rest at the beginning of the runway. And I think you can handle it from there.